# How to create unfazed pwm signals?

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, led, pwm

I have two pins with the same frequency (10Hz) and same duty cycle (50%) assigned to two different leds. How can I make the two leds blink alternatively? How can I put a delay of 50% in one of the pins?

Thanks in advance

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

L1 = 36
l2 = 37
frequency = 10

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(L1, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(L2, GPIO.OUT)

led1 = GPIO.PWM(L1, frequency)
led2 = GPIO.PWM(L2, frequency)
led1.start(50)
led2.start(50)

time.sleep(10)

led1.stop()
led2.stop()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: What you are asking for is not **asynchronous** blinking. The LEDs are still synchronous, just 180 degrees out of phase.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: Correct, but a bit of a [fine point](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+put+too+fine+a+point+on+it) methinks.

Comment: @Seamus You may think I am being pedantic, but engineers must be careful to communicate clearly. In some circumstances the difference between synchronous and asynchronous is the difference between easy and very difficult.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson: My point exactly - ***some circumstances***.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson you're totally right. I'll edit that. Thanks for the repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [lgpio Python](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/py_lgpio.html) module.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
http://abyz.me.uk/lg/py_lgpio.html
"""

import time
import lgpio as sbc

L1=16
L2=26

h = sbc.gpiochip_open(0)

sbc.gpio_claim_output(h, L1)
sbc.gpio_claim_output(h, L2)

sbc.tx_pwm(h, L1, 10, 50)
sbc.tx_pwm(h, L2, 10, 50, pulse_offset=50000)

time.sleep(20)

sbc.gpiochip_close(h)
```

[image]

Comment: I got an error saying 'module 'lgpio' has no attribute 'gpiochip_open'' ... Why does this happen?

Comment: @RaquelAlves Impossible to say without knowing what you have done and seeing the code you are using.

Comment: I tried exactly the one you provided. The lgpio package was installed but it does not recognise any function.

Comment: How did you install the package?  What does `pydoc lgpio` reported in the FILE line?

Comment: I installed using pip2 install lgpio. It worked when I imported rgpio instead of lgpio. Don't know exactly why but it does.

Comment: pip does not work with lgpio.  pip doesn't fully support Linux libraries.  You need to install manually by following the instructions at http://abyz.me.uk/lg/download.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import rgpio

L1=16
L2=26

sbc = rgpio.sbc()
h = sbc.gpiochip_open(0)

sbc.gpio_claim_output(h, L1)
sbc.gpio_claim_output(h, L2)

sbc.tx_pwm(h, L1, 10, 50)
sbc.tx_pwm(h, L2, 10, 50, pulse_offset=50000)

time.sleep(20)

sbc.gpiochip_close(h)
sbc.stop()
```